# Trying Ubuntu, New to linux

Tags: 14.04

If I do the "try" ubuntu option where I dont install it to my HDD how,but just boot Ubuntu from a flash drive, and I do not like it, how do I switch back to my Windows 8?

Comment: "Trying" Ubuntu does not install anything. Shut down the computer, pull out the USB flash memory/take out the Live DVD and turn it back on.

Answer (score 3):

Most newer computers can start up from a USB stick. You should see a welcome screen prompting you to choose your language and giving you the option to either install Ubuntu or try it from the USB.

If your computer does not automatically do this, you might need to change the device from which the computer starts up to the USB. You can usually do this by watching for a message appearing before Windows starts. You should be invited to change the boot device. Once you’ve selected that option, follow the instructions on screen.

Tip: You might be able to press ‘F12’ or ‘Escape’ while your computer is starting up to change your boot device order.

Depending on your computer and how your USB key was formatted, you should see an entry for ‘removable drive’ or ‘USB media’. Move this to the top of the list to force the computer to start from USB rather than the hard disk. Save your changes and continue.

[image]

If you select "Try" you can work in Live environment and it neither installs Ubuntu nor affects Windows previously installed (if any).

Then shutdown normally the OS which turns the PC off, remove the flash drive and when you boot it again it will work with your Windows like nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to tell your computer to boot from livecd/USB. By default PC boots from HDD, if not just plug off the disk with Ubuntu and you will return to your doors, oh sorry windows.

Comment: I Know that, if i choose not to use it, do i just shutdown, remove USB, and then it will boot from my HDD, with windows 8 like normal?

Comment: No it will eat all your programs and then your family photos for desert. Seriously, do you think you are first who afraid to just boot Ubuntu? If you paranoid you can disable HDD in BIOS or just disconnect it. But this actions are more risky and lessworthy

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like it, just reboot (remove the USB!).  The 'Try Ubuntu' option loads the OS from the USB, and allows you to manipulate Ubuntu in a live environment, but does not write to your hard disk.